# Kotlin generic interface resolver

Tags: kotlin, generics, interface, compilation, implementation

I'm trying to build a resolver that given some domain context return back an implementation of a generic interface. The code is the following (domain abstracted):

```
interface Interface<T>

class StringImplementation: Interface<String>

class BooleanImplementation: Interface<Boolean>

class Resolver {

    fun <T : Any> resolve(implementation: String): Interface<T> {
        return when (implementation) {
            "string" -> StringImplementation()
            "boolean" -> BooleanImplementation()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }

}
```

This snippet looks good to me but the compiler is complaining because `Type missmatch: Required: Interface<T> Found: StringImplementation` at line 11 and `Type missmatch: Required: Interface<T> Found: BooleanImplementation` at line 12.

Why is that a problem? I though setting `<T : Any>` in the method contract would allow to return an implementation of any type. The constraing here is that the return type of the method `resolve` must be `Interface<T>`, replacing it with `Interface<*>` would make the compiler shut up but is not what we need.

Comment: What's the point of generic here? What will happen if you call the function like `resolve<Boolean>("string")`? How will compiler be sure the Interface<T> is returned of exactly of type T provided in the function? Second problem is Interface is invariant, you have to mark T with `out` keyword to make it covariant. I'd suggest you to read https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47 if you don't know what are variances in generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

A function can have exactly 1 return type, but your function has 2 different return types.

Only this would work:

```kotlin
interface Interface<T>

class StringImplementation: Interface<String>

class BooleanImplementation: Interface<Boolean>

class Resolver {

    fun resolve(implementation: String): Interface<*> { // <-- star
        return when (implementation) {
            "string" -> StringImplementation()
            "boolean" -> BooleanImplementation()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }

}
```

### Explanation

Looking from the function definition perspective, it has to have an explicit, clear return type. `Interface<T>` says it should be something extending `Interface` and the **explicit** type `T` **which concrete implementation can be known by the start of execution** of the function.
There is no way in your code to know what `T` will be when you call `resolve`. How else would you imagine the function to know what it will return back?!

Shortened: A function can have exactly 1 return type, but your function has 2 different return types (`Interface<String>` / `Interface<Boolean>`).

[Continue to read here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generics) if you want to dig down into generics and get a more technical description.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot know if `T` matches the `implementation` variable. Even if `implementation` is `string`, `T` could be of another type then `String`. So you either can erase the generic type like @Neo mentioned or you need to cast the return type.

```
interface Interface<T>

class StringImplementation: Interface<String>

class BooleanImplementation: Interface<Boolean>

class Resolver {

    inline fun <reified T : Any> resolve(): Interface<T> {
        return when (T::class) {
            String::class -> StringImplementation() as Interface<T>
            Boolean::class -> BooleanImplementation() as Interface<T>
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
}
```

To have more type safety, you can use a reified parameter and use this to resolve the type. (Note that the cast is still necessary)

Comment: `implementation` variable is not related with the issue at all. In the real code is even not present. If you replace the when statement with `return StringImplementation()` the compilation error still there. Also, with the original snippet I posted, doing the casting `as Interface<T>` would work but I would like to avoid casting here.

Comment: This answer is almost up to the point but one big mistake is that you are trying to do an unchecked cast of incompatible types, `Interface<String>` is not a subtype of `Interface<T>`. Since Interface<T> is invariant there is no sub/super type relation between these types.

Comment: Even though `Interface<String>` is not a subtype of `Interface<T>` they are the same when `T == String`. But this cannot be assured at compile time. In this case the cast is correct (when no variance is present) and necessary.

Comment: @Trebolete The compiler needs to know the return type of a function before it is called. You could call the function that only returns the `StringImplementation` with another generic argument like `resolve<Int>()`. But the function would try to return a `String` as the generic parameter which is incompatible to `Int`. So the compiler throws an error cause it does not know how this function would be used. The type must be checked and manually casted at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> I though setting `<T : Any>` in the method contract would allow to return an implementation of any type.

No, it means it *has* to return an implementation of any type *the caller asks for*. E.g., in Animesh Sahu's example, `resolve<Boolean>("string")` must return an `Interface<Boolean>`, but your implementation of `resolve` would return a `StringImplementation`. Of course, it could also be `resolve<File>("string")` etc.

> allow to return an implementation of any type

which *the called method* chooses is exactly `Interface<*>`.